# How to confirm a log in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpclient

I am trying to write a method that i can log into an online database. It works fine, but when i write wrong user/pwd i get a message explain me that i have to put the right user/pwd, and if i try one more time with wrong user/pwd i get `"You are already logged in!"`. I don't know how to manage the inlogging?- i want the code tell me that i'm not logged in and try again?! -
Any help is very appreciate - Thanks, Steve.

There is the method (i use `BroadcastReceiver` to get the response from my `AsyncTask-onPosExecute()`) :

```
public void logIn() {
        String user = edUser.getText().toString(), pwd = edPwd.getText().toString();

        if (httpClient == null) {
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passord", pwd));

            new AsyncTaskLogIn(this).execute(new Pair<>(nameValuePairs, httpClient));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You are already logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(LogIn,
                new IntentFilter("log_in"));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver LogIn = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String result = intent.getStringExtra("myLogIn");
            tvMessage.setText(result);
        }            
    };
```

Comment: i tried what you sad (and i put: httpClient = null; next to "You aren't logged in!") , you have right. But when i'm logged in and i click a log in button i get "You aren't logged in!" and i want to get "You are already logged in!" ?!!

Comment: Yep! is a good idea! i will try it! but i would gladly continue/understand with how to manage the toast-messages for inlogging?

Comment: I am working on your suggestion, it is excellent. Quite sure that i am going to solve the problem now. thanks for your help, but how to put this answer very useful/and most helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** - Replace the string `"You are already logged in!"` with `"You aren't logged in!"`.
**2** - After logging in, simply disable/hide the login Button.
**3** - You could also set a global boolean variable `logged` to true when logged in.

In the Button's click handler, if logged, then show `"You are already logged in!"`.
Else, do the login procedure, setting `logged` to true or false depending if the login credentials match or not, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for everyone, but i like this solution, simple and effictive.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your codes seems incorrect. Change to this:

```
if (httpClient == null) {
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
} 
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passord", pwd));
new AsyncTaskLogIn(this).execute(new Pair<>(nameValuePairs, httpClient));
```

These codes ensure `httpClient` is not `null`

PS:If you want to tell whether you logged in successfully or not, you need to override the `onPostExecute` of your `AsyncTaskLogin`.

Comment: But i need a toast-messages to tell me when i have logged in/already logged in or i'm not logged in, try again. That is my problem?

Comment: i get the result/response from onPostExecute of the AsyncTaskLogin through the BroadcastReceiver(). But how to override the onPostExecute inside the mainActivity?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:This is useful to you.

```
    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
             System.out.println("is internet present:::"+isInternetPresent);
                 String username=usrname.getText().toString();
                 String password=paswd.getText().toString();

                if(!username.equals("")&&!password.equals(""))
                {


                    if(isInternetPresent)
                    {
                        System.out.println(username);
                        System.out.println(password);
                        usernamepassed=username;
                        System.out.println("inside attempt login");
                        new AttemptLogin().execute();


                    }
                else
                {

                    System.out.println("No network connection.");


                }
                }
                else if(!password.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {

                    System.out.println("Please enter username.");


                }
                else if(!username.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {

                    System.out.println("Please enter password.");


                }
                else
                {

                    System.out.println("Enter login credentials.");


                  }
            }

});
```

Async task::

```
 class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

         List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

         params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", usrname.getText().toString()));
         params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", paswd.getText().toString()));

         JsonParser jLogin = new JsonParser();
         System.out.println(usrname.getText().toString());
         System.out.println( paswd.getText().toString());
         JSONObject json = jLogin.makeHttpRequest(loginurl,"POST", params1);
         System.out.println("value for json::"+json);
         if(json!=null)
         {
             try
             {
                 if(json != null)
                 {
                 System.out.println("json value::"+json);

                 JSONObject jUser = json.getJSONObject(TAG_SRESL);
                 successL = jUser.getString(TAG_SUCCESS1);
                 username1 = jUser.getString(TAG_USERNAME );
                 password1 = jUser.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);
                 orgid=jUser.getString(TAG_ORGID);
                 role=jUser.getString(TAG_ROLE);
                 enabled=jUser.getString(TAG_ENABLED);
                 System.out.println("username value:::"+username);
                 System.out.println("password value::"+password);
                 System.out.println("role value"+role);
                 Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentSignUP);
                 }

            }

             catch(JSONException e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();

             }
          }
         else{

             successL ="No"; 
                  } 

            return null;
        }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
           super.onPostExecute(file_url);
        System.out.println("in post execute");
           pDialog.dismiss();
          if(JsonParser.jss.equals("empty"))
          {
           System.out.println("json null value");

              System.out.println("Server not connected.");


                  pDialog.dismiss();
          }
          else if(successL.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){

                System.out.println("Invalid username or password.");


              pDialog.dismiss();
           }

     }



}
```